# How to configure a new network interface in Android

Tags: android-networking

I am trying to configure a new network interface on Android tablet (v3.2).
From terminal application I can 
   "ifconfig eth0 192.168.11.14 netmask 255.255.255.0 up"
 and everything works fine (ethernet cable is connected trough USB-Ethernet dongle)

I want to make this configuration persistent, but it looks like there is no 'interfaces' file in Android.
Where is network configuration file located? Do I need to create new one? Where?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

yet another late answer... scoured the internet and couldn't find any decent answer until I checked out /etc/init.sh ...

I'm using an Android Oreo vmware image for testing purposes and here are the steps that I used to add static IP to Android on boot:

1. Open Terminal Emulator (if not present install from Play Store)
2. type `su`
3. type `vi /etc/init.sh`
4. type `i`
5. look for `function do_init()`
6. before the closing curly brace (`}`), type `post_init_network`
7. create new line after the closing curly brace (`}`), type

   `function post_init_network()`
   `{`
        `ifconfig 192.168.63.122/24 up`
    `}`

   change the ip and subnet as needed...
8. press `:wq!` to save and exit vi
9. power of and power on Android.
10. To check Static IP: 
    open Terminal Emulator again after power on, type `su`, then type `ifconfig`

NOTE: I encounter this issue where I can't get an IP from NAT network using 2 interfaces where the first interface is set to static IP and the other DHCP, just power on and power off Android until you can get an internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the really late answer. This is more for future reference.

If your ROM supports init.d scripts, try writing one for this. Put the file in `/system/etc/init.d/`, change its access mode and owner/group to `0755` and `root:root`, respectively.

Your command will be run at every boot, effectively making it persistent.